# How can I index and launch Chrome bookmarks from a launcher?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, launcher

I'm puzzled by the apparent lack of solutions for launching Chrome (or even Firefox) bookmarks from a launcher.  The Windows 7 start menu only supports IE, which is no surprise from Microsoft.  Launchy does support Firefox bookmarks, but not Chrome, and I'm trying to get away from Firefox and preferably Launchy too.

Since I more frequently launch web sites than desktop applications, and I don't want to keep a browser window cluttering my desktop all the time, I'm quite puzzled by this.  Being able to hit a single key and type a few characters to launch important web sites is just terribly useful, especially since I have ergonomic issues.  Being able to type a query like "amazon TAB Raiders of the Lost Ark" is even better (yes, Chrome can do these from the bar).

How can I get a launcher that indexes Chrome bookmarks?  Is there something I'm missing, or have things really taken such a step back from the Launchy/Firefox combo?  Do I really have to manually sit around and figure out what sites I go to recently and then create a Favorite/shortcut/whatever for each one?  Write myself a Python script that runs periodically to parse Chrome's bookmarks file and create matching Favorites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this updated weby.dll](http://home.beanalby.net/launchy.htm) for Launchy to work with your Chrome bookmarks.

> As of Launchy 2.5.0, the "weby" plugin only supports Firefox & IE
>   bookmarks. This updated weby.dll
>   supports indexing the bookmarks from
>   the default profile in Chrome. The
>   following .dll adds Chrome support to
>   weby.dll.

Note that according to [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launchy/forums/forum/677087/topic/3719069) thread it only works with Windows.

Comment: That's helpful.  I'd probably going to leave Launchy still, though, although I am still using it on my current main machine.  If I don't see anything else I'll eventually mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is old..but...if others are searching for bookmarks with Launchy now that it's a bit outdated...Built this recently. It exports Edge, Chrome (later FF if anyone needs it) bookmarks into a directory that Launchy can index and open with your default browser. Run on schedule (at login, at 4pm, etc) w/ task scheduler to keep bookmarks in sync with Launchy index.

https://github.com/jmtornetta/extract-bookmarks

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm on Mac, and I've recently noticed that Alfred indexes bookmarks (among many other things).  Safari support is built-in, for Firefox and Chrome see http://support.alfredapp.com/kb:firefox-chrome-bookmarks.